# Netbeans IDE 8.1 "Error: Could not find or load main class knowltech.KnowlTech"

Tags: java

I just started programming recently on Netbeans IDE 8.1 and the basic program helloworld also gives an error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class knowltech.KnowlTech
Error: Could not find or load main class knowltech.KnowlTech
```

**KnowlTech** is the name of my project. Would appreciate if someone could help and tell me how to deal with it in a simple language

Comment: Can you show the package structure and some code ?

Comment: package KnowlTech;


public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Eclipse!");
    }

}

Comment: run:
Error: Could not find or load main class knowltech.KnowlTech
C:\Users\Townhouse Cafe\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
This is the error, codes are running on my friends laptop, Something wrong with my laptop only

Answer (score 1):

You most likely created the wrong type of Class or you have the **Create Main Class** option unchecked.

When you create a NEW project:

- Select the New Projects button
- From the **Choose Project** dialog window select **Java** from the *Categories* pane and select **Java Application** from the *Projects* pane.
- Select the **Next** button.
- The **Name And Location** dialog window is now displayed. Enter the name of your project (*KnowlTech*).
- At the bottom of this very same dialog window make sure the **Create Main Class** *checkbox* contains a check-mark (in other words, it's enabled).

The code you are trying to work with most likely goes into the main() method that is automatically created for you.

Your project should now run properly providing you have Java installed on your specific computer.

Comment: Yes The basic hello world is working now. Thank You. Now the problem is with the bigger code.

Comment: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
This is the error.

Comment: I would suppose that you once again....did something wrong. I highly recommend you take advantage of the many tutorials available on the Internet related to NetBeans. A BUILD FAILED can be many things. The compiler should be telling you the full problem.